# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected on php image path

Tags: php, mysql, image

I am trying to display all images on a page using this query..
however it is giving me syntax problem..  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '>'

```
<?php               
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM my_image, $connection);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo "<div><img src=\"uploadedimages/".$row['name']."\" /></div>"
    }       
?>
```

anyone knows whats wrong?

Comment: Use `("SELECT * FROM my_image", $connection)` instead of `("SELECT * FROM my_image, $connection)` for "one" thing.

Comment: I suggest use some sort of syntax highlighting. or like look at your post since it does the syntax highlighting for you

Comment: Typical can of worms code. I think I'll coin this as "`C.O.W.` Code".

Comment: This really shows no attempt to debug at all. Also, you're using an outdated SQL library; `mysql_*` functions are deprecated. Consider using MySQLi or PDO.

Answer (score 3):

You're missing a closing double quote:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM my_image", $connection);
                                   ^
```

You're missing a terminating semi-colon:

```
echo "<div><img src=\"uploadedimages/".$row['name']."\" /></div>";
                                                                 ^
```

May I recommend:

```
echo '<div><img src="uploadedimages"' . $row['name'] . '" /></div>';
```

Also, stop using `mysql_` functions. They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Just an FYI to the OP, you can also embed arrays using squiggly brackets inside double quotes, like: `echo "<div><img src=\"uploadedimages/{$row['name']}\" /></div>";` (without concatenating)

Comment: @SetSailMedia You still have to escape the double quotes, which to me is too much typing.

Comment: In this instance, yes.